# How do I make my Power BI table dynamic to change with the filters the user selects?

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, dax

I have a table of calls with a column for phone number and call id. I want to create a visual that shows how many callers called how many times. (e.g. 5 callers called once, 4 called twice etc.) The challenge I am facing is that once I calculate the count of the number of callers that called count times, the table is static and is not affected by the filters on the report (e.g. the date filter).

This is what I have done so far. Is there a better way?

| CallerNumber | CallID | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | b | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | c | 2022-01-02 |
| 3 | d | 2022-01-03 |
| 4 | e | 2022-01-01 |
| 4 | f | 2022-01-05 |
| 4 | g | 2022-01-06 |

From the above original data, I created a table...

```
Table1 = 
    SUMMARIZE(
        Query,
        Query[CallerNumber],
        "Call Count", COUNT(Query[CallId])
        )
```

| CallerNumber | Call Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 |

and then another table from that table which gave me...

```
Table2 = 
    SUMMARIZE (
        'Table1',
        'Table1'[Call Count],
        "Number of Callers", COUNTROWS('Table1')
    )
```

| Call Count | Number of Callers |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

How would I instead show the below if someone were interested in calls on Jan1?

| Call Count | Number of Callers |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CalculatedTable is populated once at powerbi Model refresh, this is why it don't reflect any change in your filters.

A better option is to use a measure:

```
CountOF = CALCULATE( countrows(VALUES('Table'[CallID])))
```

Add additional "counter" table with number from 1 to 10 .

[image]

```
how manyCaller = var _virtual = ADDCOLUMNS(VALUES(detail[ids]), "CountOfCalls", [CountOF])
return
CALCULATE( countrows(FILTER(_virtual, [CountOfCalls] = SELECTEDVALUE(counter[CallCount]))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I am able to use that measure with the matrix visual to see the number of calls each phone number has, but how do I go from that to the number of callers for each number of calls?

Comment: Check my update

Comment: Thank youu!!!!!!!!!!!!